# Switching tabs programmatically not working properly

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to switch tabs programmatically using:

```
[tabBarController setSelectedIndex:index]
```

I've also tried:

```
tabBarController.selectedViewController = [tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:index];
```

It works the first time - switching both tabs and the view associated with the tab.  However it doesn't work the second time and thereafter.  Then it erratically switches the tab (not always), and doesn't switch the view controller associated with the tab.

Any ideas?

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

Tab A: I have a tab that launches the camera to take a picture and add some details.

Tab B: I have a tab with a list of pictures taken and a bar button to add a new item by taking a picture and adding details.

I'm trying to make it so that when the user taps Tab A it switches to Tab B and launches the add item method.  What's the best way to do this?

Here is more detailed code:

Tab A is hooked up to navigation controller with a UIViewController.  In that controller I have the following:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate switchView];
}
```

In AppDelegate.m I have the following:

```
- (void)switchView
{   
tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
tabBarController.selectedViewController 
= [tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:3];
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you have the correct approach, but you might have a bug in your code. Could we see the related code?

Comment: Just added some code to the question.

Answer (score 2):

The UIViewController class has a tabbarController property, so you can simplify things by calling the view controller's parent controller (the tab bar controller) instead of using the app delegate to access the tab bar controller.  Calling setSelectedIndex should be fine too.  So from inside your view controller:

```
[self.tabbarController setSelectedIndex:3];
```

To help with debugging, you could put some NSLogs in relevant places:

```
NSLog(@"The currently selected tab is: %@",self.tabbarController.selectedIndex);
```

Comment: Careful with using the index - this won't work as soon as you got more than 5 tabs (**more**-tab)

Comment: I've tried calling it directly from the file.  The tab changes in both case, but the actual view doesn't.  Or rather, the view changes exactly as it's supposed to the _first_ time, but not thereafter.

Comment: Have you tried logging out the selectedIndex in various places to help debug it?

Comment: @Till yes, good point, I'm assuming a simple tab bar app with no 'more' tab.

Comment: I figured it out.  It looks like the problem was called because I was changing the index from viewWillAppear instead of viewDidAppear.

Comment: Missing an uppercase B on the word Bar of tabBarController, thus you get an error produced.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out the problem was that I was changing the tabBarController index from viewWillAppear instead of viewDidAppear.  Must be something to do with the order in which things are loaded.